# How to configure custom themes for keycloak on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, minikube, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to configure a custom theme for login, register and forgot password pages in keycloak on kubernetes.

I am using the following url and configuration for keycloak on kubernetes.

https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube

```
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Service
            metadata:
            name: keycloak
            labels:
                app: keycloak
            spec:
            ports:
            - name: http
                port: 8080
                targetPort: 8080
            selector:
                app: keycloak
            type: LoadBalancer
            ---
            apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: Deployment
            metadata:
            name: keycloak
            namespace: default
            labels:
                app: keycloak
            spec:
            replicas: 1
            selector:
                matchLabels:
                app: keycloak
            template:
                metadata:
                labels:
                    app: keycloak
                spec:
                containers:
                - name: keycloak
                    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4
                    env:
                    - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
                    value: "admin"
                    - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
                    value: "admin"
                    - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
                    value: "true"
                    ports:
                    - name: http
                    containerPort: 8080
                    - name: https
                    containerPort: 8443
                    readinessProbe:
                    httpGet:
                        path: /auth/realms/master
                        port: 8080
```

Please suggest me any existing blog url or existing solution.

Comment: See also https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ -> `Adding a custom theme`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach that I have used on the past was to first create a .tar file (*e.g.,* `custom_theme.tar`) with the custom themes to be used in Keycloak. Then mount volume to the folder where the Keycloak themes are stored (*i.e.,* `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/my_custom_theme`), and copy the .tar file with the custom themes from a local folder into the Keycloak container.

The helm char folder structure:

```
Chart.yaml      custom_theme.tar    templates       values.yaml
```

the content of :

**values.yaml:**

```
password: adminpassword
```

The template folder structure:

```
customThemes-configmap.yaml ingress.yaml            service.yaml
deployment.yaml         secret.yaml
```

the content of :

**customThemes-configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: customthemes-configmap
binaryData:
  custom_theme.tar: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "custom_theme.tar" | b64enc}}
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - keycloak-sprint01.demo
  rules:
  - host: keycloak-sprint01.demo
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: keycloak-password
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: {{.Values.password}}
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-password
              key: password
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: "h2"
        - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/my_custom_theme
          name: shared-volume            
          
      initContainers:
        - name: init-customtheme
          image: busybox:1.28
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -rL /CustomTheme/custom_theme.tar /shared && cd /shared/ && tar -xvf custom_theme.tar && rm -rf custom_theme.tar']
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /shared
            name: shared-volume          
          - mountPath: /CustomTheme
            name: theme-volume
                   
      volumes:
      - name: shared-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: theme-volume
        configMap:
          name: customthemes-configmap
```

---

I am not claiming that this is the best way to do it, I am not an expert in Kubernetes or helm. A Git repo containing the aforementioned files can be found [here](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/minikube).

Comment: According to [the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/): A ConfigMap is not designed to hold large chunks of data. The data stored in a ConfigMap cannot exceed 1 MiB. If you need to store settings that are larger than this limit, you may want to consider mounting a volume or use a separate database or file service.

So if your theme is <1MiB why not, but for most of us this won't cut it.

Comment: @ArthurWoimbée Yep, you are right this problem was brought out in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/67588368/1366871 . When I have the time I will try to update the answer with mounting a volume instead

Answer (score 5):

you can do with initContainers using a theme image,
the theme can be maintained out side helm chart folder

```
initContainers: |
    - name: keycloak-theme-provider
      image: docker.io/my-theme:1.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - sh
      args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Copying theme..."
          cp -R /my-theme/* /theme
      volumeMounts:
        - name: theme
          mountPath: /theme

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: theme
    mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/my-theme

extraVolumes:
  - name: theme
    emptyDir: {}
```

docker image code

```
FROM busybox

COPY src/themes/ /my-theme
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do this with a private registry?

Comment: Yes. Why not? Just use the image pull secret in the deployment for your private registry and you're good to pull images into your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to make a custom Docker image that copies your theme to the correct folder.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/keycloak:latest

COPY ./themes/xential/ /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/xential/
```

And for the Helm config (I used [bitnami/keycloak](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak) helm chart):

```
image:
    registry: {{ requiredEnv "CI_REGISTRY" }}
    repository: {{ requiredEnv "IMAGE_NAME" }}
    tag: {{ requiredEnv "IMAGE_TAG" }}
    pullPolicy: Always
    pullSecrets:
      - PUTT_YOUR_SECRET_HERE_IF_PRIVATE_REGISTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference is taken from @dreamcrash answer but little more flexible.
Moving the resources to some remote http storage. Not sharing the complete config but the required ones,

First Declare Volume mounts in the deployment section:

```
   volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/keycloak/themes
          name: shared-volume
```

Then comes the declaration for a volume that will be used to mound via the init container to put your files:

```
volumes:
  - name: shared-volume
```

Define the script for init container to execute that pulls the files and extracts it to the required folder/s . This makes your theme available to be selected in the admin console.

```
  initContainers:
    - name: init-logintheme
      image: busybox:1.28
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'wget https://your_server_location/login-theme.tar.xz -P /tmp/ && tar -xvf /tmp/login-theme.tar.xz -C /opt/keycloak/themes && echo 1']
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/keycloak/themes
        name: shared-volume
```

Let me know if this helps.